# Coverage for Catch Block (cant generate exception in try{}) give another solution

Tags: apex, code-coverage, try-catch

**NOTE : This question is not duplicate.Please go through code once.**

Here is the situation -

I am calling this method from my test class, and here `My_obj__c` records are getting created and added in list, which list I insert later in "`TRY`" block (so point is I am not able to generate an exception-by making list empty or something like that from test Class)

```
private boolean mymethod(){
      My_obj__c obj = new My_obj__c(name='test');

      List<My_obj__c> lst = new List<My_obj__c>();
      lst.add(obj);

try{
    insert lst;
   }
   catch(Exception e){
         /////////// 15 lines code --- need to cover
   }
}
```

Any Solution, suggestions, help. Please reply.

Comment: Is it `catch (DmlException e)` or `catch (Exception e)`?

Comment: Here's what I would ask, if you can't manually generate an error then what type of error are you expecting to find once this is working?

Comment: @KeithC  - Its catch(Exception e){ }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add this to the code:

```
try {
    insert lst;
    TestOptions.throwDmlException();
} catch(Exception e){
    ...
}
```

where the added class is (as a `DmlException` can be constructed):

```
public class TestOptions {
    public static Boolean throwDmlException = false;
    public static void throwDmlException() {
        if (throwDmlException) throw new DmlException();
    }
}
```

and then in your test case turn the option on where needed:

```
TestOptions.throwDmlException = true;
```

Comment: This looks great, but one more thing - Can we do it without updating/chaning my Class code ?

Comment: @NileshMendhe No. This approach requires a change to the code you are testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a empty object which will give exception while insertion

```
 My_obj__c obj = new My_obj__c();
```

Also, as mentioned in above comment by Keith which exception you are catching catch (DmlException e) or catch (Exception e)?

```
try{
    insert lst;
   }
   catch(Exception e){
         /////////// 15 lines code --- need to cover
   }
}
```

Comment: catch(Exception e)

Comment: No, I cant change the Class functionality by adding Empty object. I have to do it from TestClass  ORRRRR if no then not changing any Logic of Class/Controller which is already working fine

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<My_obj__c> lst = new List<My_obj__c>();
      lst.add(obj);

try{
    insert lst;
     if(Test.isRunning)
    {
      Integer i = 1/0;
     }
   }
   catch(Exception e){
         /////////// 15 lines code --- need to cover
   }
}
```

Please note the point mentioned by @cropredy below

> small issue here -- the exception will be thrown for all testmethods -
>   including ones that need to legitimately and successfully insert
>   my_obj__c. You need to have the testmethod signal the try block that
>   it wants to have an exception thrown. Pravesh has a better solution
>   for triggering a DML exception - omit a required field

Comment: small issue here -- the exception will be thrown for all testmethods - including ones that need to legitimately and successfully insert `my_obj__c`. You need to have the testmethod signal the try block that it wants to have an exception thrown.  Pravesh has a better solution for triggering a DML exception - omit a required field